# find and replace string in a file

Tags: file, shell, scripting, replace

I'm trying to find and replace a string in a folder of files.

Could someone possibly help me?

My script is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
OLD="This is a"
NEW="I am a"
DPATH="/home/user/test/*.txt"
BPATH="/home/user/test/backup/foo"
[ ! -d $BPATH ] && mkdir -p $BPATH || :
for f in $DPATH
do
  if [ -f $f -a -r $f ]; then
    /bin/cp -f $f $BPATH
    sed "s/$OLD/$NEW/g" "$f"
   else
    echo "Error: Cannot read $f"
  fi
done
```

Now this seems to find the string 'This is a' and replaces with 'I am a', but this only prints to screen.

I need it to replace in the files themselves.

Thanks

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Use the `-i` option of  `sed` to make the changes in place:

```
sed -i "s/$OLD/$NEW/g" "$f"
    ^^
```

Comment: Worked great! I knew I'd missed something. Thanks

Comment: Ok, is there an easy way to modify my shell script, so that it will check in subfolders? /home/user/test/xyz ?

Comment: #!bin/bash
    OLD="This is a"
    NEW="I am a"
    BPATH="/home/user/backup/foo"
    find . -name '*.shtml' -type f |
    while read filename
    do
        /bin/cp -f $filename $BPATH
        sed -i "s/$OLD/$NEW/g" $filename
    done

Comment: I am receiving this error when trying to use -i: sed: illegal option -- i
Usage: sed [-n] [-e script] [-f source_file] [file...]

Comment: @Dchris The `-i` option isn't entirely portable, though it's supported in some form on most platforms. On *BSD (including MacOS) you need `-i ''`; if you don't have `sed -i` at all, maybe try `perl -pi -e ` where a simple `sed` script can be use in Perl verbatim, but notice that the regex dialects differ (you mainly need to understand how backslashes need to be added or removed in some places).

Answer (score 2):

The output goes to screen (`stdout`) because of the following:

```
sed "s/$OLD/$NEW/g" "$f"
```

Try redirecting to a file (the following redirects to a new files and then renames it to overwrite the original file):

```
sed "s/$OLD/$NEW/g" "$f" > "$f.new" && mv "$f.new" "$f"
```

Comment: That creates a .text.new file and the original file, example.txt is overwritten and is blank. Any ideas why?

Comment: @user390426: It could be because aix didn't quote the variables `"$f.new"' (two places) and `"$f"`. Also, the `mv` shouldn't be unconditional. Instead, it should be `sed ... && mv ...`.

Comment: Ok, I have now changed $OLD to be a URL and it returns an error: sed: couldn't open file ww.google.co.uk//g: No such file or directory the 'sed' command doesn't seem to like the // part of the url. Is there a way to overcome this?

Comment: @user390426: Change the delimiter in the `sed` command: `"s|$OLD|$NEW|g"`.

Answer (score 0):

this is a snippet i use, it removes all stuff between APA and BEPA (across multiple lines, including removing APA, BEPA) in all files below current directory, exclude the .svn directory

```
find . \! -path '*.svn*' -type f -exec sed -i -n '1h;1!H;${;g;s/APA[ \t\r\n]*BEPA//g;p}' {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out

http://cs.boisestate.edu/~amit/teaching/handouts/cs-unix/node130.html

```
##########################################################
\#!/bin/sh

\# sed/changeword

prog=`basename $0`

case $# in
0|1) echo 'Usage:' $prog '<old string> <new string>'; exit 1;;
esac

old=$1
new=$2
for f in *
do
        if test "$f" != "$prog"

        then
            if test -f "$f"
            then
                sed "s/$old/$new/g" $f > $f.new
                mv $f $f.orig
                mv $f.new $f
                echo $f done
            fi
        fi
done

##############################################################
```