# Bash ,Find and Replace a string with a parameterized value generated inside the code?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

Below link I have already tried but failed :

[find and replace string in a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4437901/find-and-replace-string-in-a-file)

It's seems to be very easy solve but I am stuck and not able to resolve

So I have a file inside which there are multiple fields like below :

```
env : $env

user : abc

passowrd : xyv

tablename : cat_$env 

tablelocation : hdfs://home/ak/cat_$env
```

So my requirement is to replace `$env` with `$env_details` ( which I am generating inside my shell script )
means value of `$env_details` keep on changing on every run , I have tried below command but got error :

```
sed -i "s/$env/$env_details/g" "$filename"
```

`Error: sed: -e expression #1 , char 0  no previous regular expression`

Could you please help out with my mistake?

Comment: You have to escape the variables. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/407523/escape-a-string-for-a-sed-replace-pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is that the shell tries to expand `$env` if it is inside double quotes, just as it expands `$filename`. Simply write

```
sed -i 's/$env/$env_details/g' "$filename"
```

If you want to replace by `$env_details` contents, keep the double quotes and escape the `$` of `$env`:

```
sed -i "s/\$env/$env_details/g" "$filename"
```